# SQL Join setting value from table2 to table1 where id is the same

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

i've the following table

```
+-----+------+
| sID | name |
+-----+------+
|   2 | MXX  |
|   3 | ISS  |
|   4 | FSS  |
|   5 | SSA  |
|   6 | PSA  |
+-----+------+
```

and the following table

```
+-----+-------+
| sID | pname | 
+-----+-------+
|   1 | qqq   |      
|   1 | yyy   |         
|   2 | zzz   |
|   1 | lll   |
|   2 | mmm   | 
|   3 | ttt   |
|   3 | sss   |
|   5 | xxx   |
|   5 | iii   |
+-----+-------+
```

and the join result should look like

```
+-----+-------+----------+
| sID | pname | supplier |
+-----+-------+----------+
|   1 | qqq   |          |
|   1 | yyy   |          |
|   2 | zzz   | MXX      |
|   1 | lll   |          |
|   2 | mmm   | MXX      |
|   3 | ttt   | ISS      |
|   3 | sss   | ISS      |
|   5 | xxx   | SSA      |
|   5 | iii   | SSA      |
+-----+-------+----------+
```

idea is to put the values of column `name` from first table in the second table where `sID` is the same

i tried `Select * From TABLE1  c LEFT join TABLE2 T on c.sID=T.sID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your left join is the wrong way around.

```
 select table2.sid, pname, table1.name as supplier 
 from table2  
    left join table1 on table2.sid = table1.sid
```

or change your `left join` to a `right join`